# Discord.js - How to toggle a command in 1 server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of building a discord bot with a command handler and a few meme commands. My problem is, that when I activate 'Christian Mode' or 'no swear mode' it activates across every server the bot is in. My Christian mode code is here, across Christian.js and Index.js.

**Christian.js**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

exports.run = (bot, message, args, christian) => {
  if (args[0] === 'off') christian = false
  else if (args[0] === 'on') christian = true
  message.channel.send(`Christian Mode ${christian ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}`)
  return christian
}

exports.help = {
  name: 'christian'
}
```

**(part of) index.js**

```js
if (christian) {
    const messages = {
      flib: 'frick',
      batch: 'nasty person',
      nogger: 'nibba',
      nafga: 'smelly person',
      poohsy: 'child',
      poohsyhole: 'child',
      cant: 'threat to society',
      bestard: 'threat to society',
      dock: 'willy'
    }
    try {
      const message = messages[content.toLowerCase()]
      if (message) msg.delete() & channel.send(message).then((m) => m.delete(10000));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('An error has occurred - make sure the bot has delete message permissions')
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance :)
**New code:**

```js
if (content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    const args = content.toLowerCase().substring(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g)
    const command = args.shift()

    readdir(join(__dirname, 'commands')).then(files => {
      files.map(file => require(join(__dirname, 'commands', file))).forEach(cmd => {
        if (command === cmd.help.name) {
          const resultchristian = cmd.run(bot, msg, args, christian)
          if (typeof resultchristian !== 'undefined') christian = resultchristian
        }
      })
    })
    return
  }
```

this is my prefix and command handler, is there anything I need to alter for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set christian to object and then add message.guild.id as property with any value (true or false)
Like this

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

exports.run = (bot, message, args, christian) => {
  if (args[0] === 'off') christian[message.guild.id] = false
  else if (args[0] === 'on') christian[message.guild.id] = true
  message.channel.send(`Christian Mode ${christian[message.guild.id] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}`)
  return christian
}

exports.help = {
  name: 'christian'
}
```

```js
let christian = {}

if (christian[message.guild.id]) {
    const messages = {
      flib: 'frick',
      batch: 'nasty person',
      nogger: 'nibba',
      nafga: 'smelly person',
      poohsy: 'child',
      poohsyhole: 'child',
      cant: 'threat to society',
      bestard: 'threat to society',
      dock: 'willy'
    }
    try {
      const message = messages[content.toLowerCase()]
      if (message) msg.delete() & channel.send(message).then((m) => m.delete(10000));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('An error has occurred - make sure the bot has delete message permissions')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer :) part of it is working but I fear I've messed it up because of another line, ill add something to the code I've posted. The error thrown is  if (christian[message.guild.id]) {
                ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined

Comment: After changing message to msg, it worked, but my words are not replaced

Comment: try console.log (christian[message.guild.id]), what`s it output?

Comment: I cannot get it to output anything, its very strange no matter what I alter - changed a few lines and it output 'undefined'

Comment: if you want, add my discord Proto#4992 and we can discuss some stuff there

Comment: i can\`t use discord right now.. I did some changes `return christian` the right way here. So now i\`ts must work :) I\`m not sure about `christian[message.guild.id]`, if you declarate `message` as `msg` in this module, you need change it to `christian[msg.guild.id]`

Comment: for some strange reason I cant work out, when I type '=Christian on or off' it always says Christian mode active

Comment: For right check need add guild.id like  `message.channel.send(\`Christian Mode ${christian[message.guild.id] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}\`)`

Comment: Something strange is happening, I’m gonna try fixing it, but it’s very odd

Comment: I don’t see how your `command.run` function works, and whether it returns a value. Therefore, it is difficult for me to say. When you use the command, do the values ​​in the message in which you display the status change?

Comment: And you need put `let christian = {}` into your main js file, not command execute.

Comment: The command.run function works, and the messages appear, however the actual function does not, I will also make sure let Christian = { } is in the correct place, thank you in advance